# Is it a good practice to store html page in room database?

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack, persistent-storage

> Scenario: Need to display 100+ questions on a screen. (Each **question
>   text** and **option value** are coming as HTML page from server).

I was trying to store **question text** and **option value** in the room database. Is this a better approach?

(**If not**)

Please suggest me a better way of storing the HTML page in the room database?

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to store the question and options in your db and populate a single HTML template from those. This will allow you to change the look and feel of your pages without needing to repopulate the db with new pages.

Comment: Storing HTML Pages in Database and retrieving them will take some time? Seems to be not responsive?

Comment: Assuming your pages are all the same, save for the text, you are storing a lot of extra information with no benefit. This not only affects total storage needed, but impacts performance on table reads as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the data only as it is received, then the only thing to consider is the size. If it won't occupy much space, then you can go with this approach.

If you use only relevant data parsed from the HTML page you received, or if storing it as HTML will consume too much space, better parse the data beforehead and save it as separately in different columns.